# How to collect data on number of app opens

Tags: java, android, android-studio, event-tracking

I'm looking for a way to track how often an app I create is opened and what activities are launched the most.

Would this data automatically be tracked in the Play Console?  I do not have a Playstore developer account since apps I created are for internal corporate use. Would I still be able to collect this data if the app were privately uploaded?  This app would only be available to internal users.

Are there other data collection methods that better track this information?

Comment: You generally turn to an analytics solution to track stuff like this.  Google Analytics is an example.

Comment: The terms you should be searching for is "mobile analytics sdk". There are variety of vendors that can provide such a service.